# How to change property value of a view inside CarouselView's ItemTemplate?

Tags: xamarin.forms, maui, .net-maui

I have a `CarouselView` with `ItemTemplate` containing a `Label` and a `Grid`. Outside of that `CarouselView`, I want to make a button to modify Carousel's current item's Grid's visibility. Because it's inside `ItemTemplate`, I can't use `x:Name` to refer to that specific Grid, so how can I refer to the current item's Grid so I can change its property value? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will want to do that through databinding. As you already mentioned, you can't use `x:Name`. This is because you're inside of a template. The value in `x:Name` would be duplicated for each time that template is applied to a concrete item in your list, in this case a `CarouselView`. Moreover; if you use virtualization for that list, a template might not even exist at all at that point in time. All reasons why you can't use `x:Name` to reference anything inside of a template.

I don't have any info about the code you want to use this with, so I'll make something up.

If the backing collection for your `CarouselView` is a `ObservableCollection<MyItem>`, then your `CarouselView` might look something like this:

```xml
<!-- Databinding scope here is MyViewModel -->
<CarouselView ItemsSource="{Binding MyItemsCollection}">
    <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
        <!-- Databinding scope here is MyItem -->
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Text="Delete" IsVisible="{Binding CanDelete}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
</CarouselView>
```

So you will have a backing view model which has a `MyItemsCollection`, and your page (that holds the `CarouselView`) has set the `BindingContext` to a new instance of `MyViewModel`:

```cs
public class MyViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<MyItem> MyItemsCollection { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<MyItem>();

    private void LoadData()
    {
        var items = _myItemService.GetItems();

        foreach (var item in items)
        {
           MyItemsCollection.Add(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Whenever you want to influence the `IsVisible` you will want to set the `CanDelete` of the `MyItem` that it's about to `false`. Let's assume `MyItem` looks like this:

```cs
public class MyItem
{
    public bool CanDelete { get; set; }
}
```

You will need to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface on it so that the UI will pick up on any changes that are made to property values.

Now whenever you set the `CanDelete` of a certain instance of `MyItem` to false, that will change your UI. E.g.: `MyItemsCollection[3].CanDelete = false;`

On my YouTube channel I added [a playlist](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Or_qn8i8jVM&list=PLfbOp004UaYWOuVUuEtGlpkDIC1houhn_) with videos about data binding which might help in cases like these.

PS. At the time of writing `IsVisible` is bugged in .NET MAUI

Comment: Thank you! but may I ask what the bug is? Because I'm working with .NET MAUI and the IsVisible binding and notifypropertychange seems to be fine.

Comment: That's great! Then just make sure to not upgrade to the latest Visual Studio I guess :P This was the bug: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/8044 it's fixed now but not released yet